# AsyncTask doInBackground returning a nullpointerexception only sometimes

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-asynctask

Getting this error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.Wahoo.BrowseListActivity$DownloadSite.doInBackground(BrowseListActivity.java:79)
at com.Wahoo.BrowseListActivity$DownloadSite.doInBackground(BrowseListActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
... 4 more
```

Here's my AsyncTask...it crashes only for some users at particular times...not sure why. Perhaps they lose their internet connection mid-query? What am I doing wrong here? Here's my code:

```
private class DownloadSite extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private HttpResponse response;
        private InputStream in;
        private Context context;
        private String html;
        private ProgressDialog progress;


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            in = null;

            String url = "aURLGOESHERE_BUTI'MCENSORING"                                 + params[0] + "";

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                response = client.execute(request);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            html = null;

            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            } catch (Exception e) {

                this.publishProgress();
                this.cancel(true);

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            html = params[0] + str.toString();

            return html;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            progress = new ProgressDialog(BrowseListActivity.this);
            progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            progress.setMessage("Loading...");
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

            CharSequence text = "Connection interrupted...please try again";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,
                    duration);
            toast.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String html) {
            progress.dismiss();

            Context context = BrowseListActivity.this;
            Intent stopViewer = new Intent(context, StopActivity.class);
            stopViewer.setData(Uri.parse(html + ""));
            context.startActivity(stopViewer);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Which like of code is line 79?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that you are doing wrong is continuing to execute `doInBackground` after an error that makes it impossible to continue meaningfully. For instance:

```
try {
    response = client.execute(request);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

If this throws an exception, `response` is going to be `null` and there's no point in proceeding further. You'll generate a `NullPointerException` in the next block of code. That won't be fatal, because you are catching all exceptions there. Further on, though, this pattern repeats and you aren't catching all exceptions.

You should exit prematurely, returning `null` as the String result. Then you can test for a `null` in `onPostExecute` and let the user know what happened in a graceful way.

Comment: Thats right - any HTTP call should account for a null response. You could do the null-check in the `doInBackground()` but it really keeps things clean if you return null and do the null check in `onProgressUpdate()` or `onPostExecute()` as the case may be.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I'll look into this and accept this response if I find this worked. Thanks for the great feedback.